# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Date/Heure' of undefined

Tags: json, angular, typescript, object, rxjs

My web application get data from a .mes file when we upload it & play with data to insert it in an Object.
On load, there is nothing in the object, & after upload the file, the datas come

I want to display the 'date' I get on .mes with this :

Production date : {{ jsonToDisplay[0]['Date/Heure']['Date'] }}

At the end, the jsonToDiplay have a lot of data and never the same et never the same "model" so I can't create one. Moreover, I tried async methode but nothing, on init, the jsonToDisplay = [];

Comment: need more details to help you but the error message say jsonToDisplay[0] is undefined how to you recover this variable ?

Comment: Before I upload my file, jsonToDisplay = [] - when i upload it, the jsonToDisplay[0]['Date/Heure']['Date'] exists, so I just want to remove the error on load

Answer (score 0):

Normally, to remove the error we can do this :
{{ jsonToDisplay[0]?.Date/Heure?.Date }}, but because of the 'Date"/"Heure, it's impossible.

So i put the value in new variable in the Typescript & it works